# How to display a transparent video in HTML5?

Tags: html5-video, mp4

I am having issue with this code:

```
import myTitle from "../../image/earth.mov";

function Hero() {
  return (
    <div className="section-hero">
       <video autoPlay loop muted>
          <source src={ofobTitle} type="video/mov" />
       </video>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Hero;
```

It will not show / load the desired video. When I test the same code using mp4 the video works perfectly.

My issue is that I cannot allow for the video to be converted to mp4 as I need to retain the alpha channels.

Does anyone know a way around this problem?

Comment: What is the video codec in the MOV? Use a tool like **MediaInfo** to check (download it) if you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.mov` file likely is using `H.265/HEVC` encoding, which is only supported by Safari browser. You'll need to convert it to a web compatible format like **WebM** (which has alpha channel).

Check out https://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2021/10/alpha-video-in-html5.html for details.